# getting last modified items

Tags: bash, awk

**Input file:**
name/path/date_modified

```
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-03-24
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-17
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-03-18
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-02-16
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-03-19
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-02-21
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-13
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-02-20
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-03-03
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-02-21
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-02-22
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-01-15
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-02-17
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-02-14
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-04-14
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-15
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-04-12
```

I'm trying to find files which were modified in given directory after given date:

e.g. Find files modified after `2015-02-22` in path `/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/`

My solution is trying to transfer date from format `YYYY-MM-DD` to `YYYYMMDD`, because then I can compare them like a number

**Output:**

```
omg.txt
wtf.txt
```

My code is here (it doesn't work though):

```
my_date=2015-02-22
wdate=$(echo $my_date | tr -d "-")
my=$(awk -F"|" -v tgt="$path"  '($2==tgt) {print $3}' $input | tr -d "-"| awk -F"|" '($0=="$wdate"){print $1}' $input)
```

Comment: Why isn't `lol.txt` in the output? (`lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-03-18`)

Comment: @jaypalsingh because it's in dir /twitter...i find only /face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can pass the date without `-` you can remove the `gsub` for `date` variable.

```
awk -v date="2015-02-22" -F'|' '
    $2=="/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/" {
        gsub(/-/, "", $3)
        gsub(/-/, "", date)
        if ($3>date && !a[$1]++)
            print $1
}' file
```

Comment: can you describe me what does `!a[$1]++` this part of code...?

Comment: @DRINK It is an `awk` idiom to remove the duplicates.

Comment: i just realized this: if the file is deleted, record of opening stays in Input file, but it won't appear in printout...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

gawk `>` can do [string comparison](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html#Comparison-Operators)...

```
my_date=2015-02-22

$ awk -v "my_date=$my_date" -F'|' '$NF>my_date' < input-file.txt
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-03-24
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-17
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-03-18
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|2015-03-19
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-13
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-03-03
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|2015-04-14
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-03-15
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|2015-04-12
```